# Moving items in Content Editor bypasses Workflow in Sitecore

Tags: workflow

Let's say that we have a bunch of items that are already published, meaning that their workflow status must be something like `_final`. When we move those items from a folder to another in the Content Editor, the workflow status remains the same.

However, I would prefer those items moved from a folder to another folder checked, not just showing those contents to public without any controls.

Is it possible to set the workflow status to something like `_Draft` so that the user must start their workflow from the beginning when they move their items (contents) to other folders?

Comment: I am going to assume you're using the sitecore sample workflow. For your knowledge a item wont move draft > final back to draft. What happens is draft > final then new version of the item is created and the process starts over. To answer your specific question if you want to change what happens when you copy an item you will have to hook into one of the pipelines and write some custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the event `item:moved`. In this pipeline, when the item has already been moved, you can update the workflow state.

```
public void OnItemMovedEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var eventArgs = args as SitecoreEventArgs;

    if (eventArgs == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var item = eventArgs.Parameters[0] as Item;

    // Apply some logics to see if item workflow should be updated

    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {       
        item.Editing.BeginEdit();
        item.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value = "{190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC}";
        item.Editing.EndEdit();     
    }
}
```

Note that I am assuming you are using the Sample Workflow. If you are using a custom one, you need to update the `ID` at the statement

```
item.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value = "{190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC}";
```

Once completed, you need to add it to the item event pipeline via config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
        <event name="item:saved">
            <handler type="YourNamespace.ClassName,YourAssembly" method="OnItemMovedEvent" />
        </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hishaam! Thanks a lot for your answer. It worked!

Comment: @Tama can you please approved the answer so that it may help others